# PHP built in webserver and Document root folder

Tags: php

So I'm watching Laracasts videos and got confused on how he got the document to listen to a folder on his desktop?

[image]

in the picture attached is a screenshot of his document root folder listening on php-learning folder on the Desktop similar to mine. I'm using OS X EL Capitan.  My document root says /Users/myname

I'm using the terminal to call php -S localhost:8888

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, when you're working with a PHP server through command line make sure in terminal you change directory CD into the folder and start the server within the terminal php -S localhost:whateveryoupick.

Answer (score 1):

for everyone else like me who looking for fast answer here is command to start PHP server with specified folder listing

```
php -S localhost:2376 -t /var/www/tmp
```

for windows user path are different it will be like `c:\www\tmp` 
If you need to run this server continually add it to your system startup path , 
in linux run

```
$ crontab -e
@reboot  php -S localhost:2376 -t /var/www/tmp
```

in windows create bat file e.g phpserver.bat and add to it `php -S localhost:2376 -t c:\www\tmp` and grape phpserver.bat to startup folder `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Answer (score 0):

PHP does provide a single threaded built in web server for development purpose. From php.net....

> As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server.
>
> The web server runs a only one single-threaded process, so PHP
>   applications will stall if a request is blocked.
>
> URI requests are served from the current working directory where PHP
>   was started, unless the -t option is used to specify an explicit
>   document root. If a URI request does not specify a file, then either
>   index.php or index.html in the given directory are returned. If
>   neither file exists, the lookup for index.php and index.html will be
>   continued in the parent directory and so on until one is found or the
>   document root has been reached. If an index.php or index.html is
>   found, it is returned and $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is set to the trailing
>   part of the URI. Otherwise a 404 response code is returned.

Comment: so how do I go about doing this in the terminal to call a folder on my desktop called php-learning to be the document root

Comment: You can use -t in the command line. php -S localhost:8888 -t Users/myname

Comment: well the folder I'm actually trying to call is on my desktop it's called php-learning, so would it be php -S localhost:8888 -t /Desktop/php-learning/ ?

Comment: Yes it would be your directory path you get in your address bar